# How to open a '.. ' file in linux?

Tags: linux, vim, filesystems

Short intro to the story:

On of my VPS servers got hacked. While trying to asses the damage, I have noticed most of the 'owned' php files have encrypted code (via base64 and eval) - no pattern to match them all. But I have also noticed in the folders via ftp there's a '..' file showing up, which everywhere it shows has the same first line of text: 'vFPuWN80hSq17G4OF8oyhg==' .

While I can download,delete,rename these '..' files via FTP I can't find a reliable way to work with them via shell. vim and nano show me the parent directory listing when invoked with '..' ... .

So short question how can I open/delete/edit/stat a .. file in linux?

[image]

*Edit (1)*

As suggested by @zmo the file's name is actually '../'. However it appears as '..' if I run find or grep to locate it:

[image]

*Edit (2)*

As it can be noticed from the image above the file name is actually `..`.

Which can be opened with `vim '.. '`.

Comment: this question is not a programming question, and should be migrated over [SU](http://superuser.com) or [SF](http://serverfault.com). Actually if I could redo my closing vote, I guess I'd choose the later ;-)

Comment: The name is `..\ `, not `../`

Comment: @KeithThompson so the '/' at the end does not show up in grep, find and FTP listing because of it's specialness?

Comment: There cannot and `/` character in a file name; it's a directory delimiter, and the filesystem doesn't allow it. As I said, you don't have a `/` char, you have a ``\ ` character. Any `/` character you see was add by `ls -F`. You may also have a directory whose name consists of two spaces. If you want help, post to http://unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: Hmm, after some more digging, actually the file's name is `.. ` - dotdot followed by space, and can be opened using `vim '.. '` or nano. Thanks everyone for comments.

Answer (score 1):

given the output you're giving, it's not a `..` file but a `..\` file, so you should open it by doing:

```
vim ..\\
```

or

```
vim '..\'
```

and by the way, if you got a round robin completion mechanism, like in zsh, you can do `..<tab>` twice, which will give you a way to use the `..\` file.

Comment: tried both, but I get [New file] ... could it be because I am using putty...?

Answer (score 1):

The name of this file seems to actually be `..\`, i.e. two dots followed by a backslash.

You should be able to edit/delete it by using standard shell filename quoting/escaping mechanisms: [escaping](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/escapingsection.html) via backslashes, or [strong quoting](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/quotingvar.html) with single quotes:

```
rm '..\'
```